# Pandas not loading in JupyterLab

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda

Been working on a data science project for a few weeks in JupyterLab using Python 3 and Pandas w/o any issues. Today I can't load pandas via the standard `import pandas as pd` . (see error message below)

I've tried checking to make sure pandas is installed in my Anaconda environment. After sourcing my Anaconda environment I've run both `pip list` and `conda list` and both show pandas 0.25.0 as installed in the packages list for the Anaconda environment.

Wondering if this might be related to a recent update of JupyterLab to version 1.0.2 and update of Jupyter Notebook to version 6.0.0?

I expect `import pandas as pd` to work fine but instead I get:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-2-7dd3504c366f> in <module>
    ----> 1 import pandas as pd

    ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py in <module>
         40 import pandas.core.config_init
         41 
    ---> 42 from pandas.core.api import *
         43 from pandas.core.sparse.api import *
         44 from pandas.tseries.api import *

    ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/api.py in <module>
         24 )
         25 from pandas.core.arrays import Categorical, array
    ---> 26 from pandas.core.groupby import Grouper
         27 from pandas.io.formats.format import set_eng_float_format
         28 from pandas.core.index import (Index, CategoricalIndex, Int64Index,

    ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/__init__.py in <module>
          1 from pandas.core.groupby.groupby import GroupBy  # noqa: F401
    ----> 2 from pandas.core.groupby.generic import (  # noqa: F401
          3     SeriesGroupBy, DataFrameGroupBy, PanelGroupBy)
          4 from pandas.core.groupby.grouper import Grouper  # noqa: F401

    ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py in <module>
         40 import pandas.core.indexes.base as ibase
         41 from pandas.core.internals import BlockManager, make_block
    ---> 42 from pandas.core.panel import Panel
         43 from pandas.core.series import Series
         44 

    ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/panel.py in <module>
       1584                   docs={})
       1585 
    -> 1586 ops.add_special_arithmetic_methods(Panel)
       1587 ops.add_flex_arithmetic_methods(Panel)
       1588 Panel._add_numeric_operations()

    ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/__init__.py in add_special_arithmetic_methods(cls)
        810         special methods will be defined and pinned to this class
        811     """
    --> 812     _, _, arith_method, comp_method, bool_method = _get_method_wrappers(cls)
        813     new_methods = _create_methods(
        814         cls, arith_method, comp_method, bool_method, special=True

    ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/__init__.py in _get_method_wrappers(cls)
        717         comp_special = _comp_method_FRAME
        718         bool_special = _arith_method_FRAME
    --> 719     return arith_flex, comp_flex, arith_special, comp_special, bool_special
        720 
        721 

    UnboundLocalError: local variable 'arith_flex' referenced before assignment
```

Thanks for any help or suggestions.

Comment: If you've updated with conda, you won't have pandas 0.25 yet.  However, if you updated pandas with pip, you've probably broken a dependency.  I'd recommend removing pandas and reinstalling it with conda if you're using a conda env.  I only every use pip for packages not available from conda, so I don't break things.

Comment: @Trenton_M thanks for the suggestion. i believe it worked earlier this week with pandas 0.25, but uninstalling and reinstalling is worth a try. I will update once that's completed.

Comment: @Trenton_M Thanks for your suggestion. Reinstall of Anaconda solved issues.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately I solved this dependency issue by uninstalling and reinstalling Anaconda using [this guide](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-anaconda-on-ubuntu-18-04/#uninstalling-anaconda). This was in part aligned with @Trenton_M 's suggestion/info above as the reinstall rolled Pandas back from version 0.25.0 to version 0.24.2 while keeping JupyterLab version 1.0.2 and Jupyter Notebook version 6.0.0.

```
pandas.__version__
```

output

```
'0.24.2'
```

which is the [default version listed for Anaconda](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/packages/py3.7_linux-64/).

Comment: Just remember, don't update packages in the `conda` environment with `pip`.  It will most likely corrupt your environment.  That said, I have to periodically reinstall `Anaconda`, thought its gotta better. I haven't had any issues installing packages with `pip` that aren't currently available with `conda`.

Comment: `conda install pandas=0.25.0` if you want the current version.  It will install from `conda-forge`, so you may need to have `- conda-forge` under `channels` in the `.condarc` file.  You can look that up separately.