# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'arith_flex' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda

I was teaching a workshop today, and 5 people in my class had the error mentioned above when they used the line `import pandas as pd`.

Here's the traceback:

[image]

I've never heard of this variable before, and there was no mention of this particular issue with pandas in this particular context.

Some background:

- These people were on corporate computers, so there may have been permissions denied to them on their own computer
- They couldn't get regular Anaconda Navigator working, so they were using miniconda
- This error message showed up when they tried to import pandas and seaborn, but not matplotlib or sklearn
- they had done the install a week before, and no one mentioned having touched the software in the meantime
- this simulaltaneously happened on 5 different people's computers

Any idea what the issue may have been?

Comment: Very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57225013/494134)

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue. I uninstalled Pandas and reinstalled with version 0.25.1 which seemed to fix the issue. Must have been a bug.

Comment: For me installing version 0.25.0 helped solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

While it's not clear how this is happening, I think it is clear that for the Panel class, somehow [this method](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/ops/__init__.py#L675) is being called, and none of the logic cases are being satisfied, so that the return statement ends up with an unbound local problem.

Perhaps a recent version of pandas was release where the refactoring was committed for some subset of the files, but the changes weren't made for Panel?

I notice that in the `generic.py` file where the erroneous import is happening, from [pandas source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py) it does not appear to contain that import any more. That Panel import was introduced [in this commit](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/21820/commits/782a56815f1556fd2eaa13e7f95099167b24b09c) and was removed [in this commit](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/commit/776530cc62d3d0f58c20a95b79776d9c69a2dbf2) related to v0.26.0 and v0.25.0.rc0.